# Is This An Efficient Way To Remove All Lines From A File That Do Not Contain A Certain String?

Tags: c#

Title say it all - I'm trying to remove every line from a file that contains the string "PresenceManager" I first loop through the file, removing any instance of the string. However, this leaves a TON of empty lines, so I have to go and remove those with another block of code. This seems like quite a lot of code to do such a seemingly easy task. Is their any way to shorten/optimize this?

```
 public static void checkDirtyLogs(Skype s, Form1 f1)
    {
        foreach (string log in Directory.GetFiles(f1.path, "debug*.log"))
        {

            string[] currentFile = File.ReadAllLines(log);

            for (int i = 0; i < currentFile.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (!currentFile[i].Contains("PresenceManager"))
                {
                    currentFile[i] = "";
                }
            }

            File.WriteAllLines(log, currentFile);

            var tempFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
            try
            {
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(log))
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(tempFileName))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                            streamWriter.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
                File.Copy(tempFileName, log, true);
            }
            finally
            {
                File.Delete(tempFileName);
            }

        }

    } //Clean logs
```

Comment: grep -v PresenceManager filename

Comment: @whatsisname: It being C#, he's probably on Windows (unless he happens to be using Mono on Ubuntu or somesuch).  On Windows, the equivalent is most likely [`FINDSTR`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416241).

Comment: @RobertHarvey In which case he can use cygwin :)

Comment: It is great to have plenty of options, including [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question asks for critique on existing, working code. Such questions have a home at [codereview.se]

Comment: Sorry for posting it in the wrong section, will not do that in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Create two streams, one with the input and one with the output:

```
using(var reader = new StreamReader(log))
using(var writer = new StreamWriter(tempFile))
```

2) Read each line from the `reader`, check it and write to the writer if if passes

```
while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
     if(!line.Contains("PresenceManager"))
     {
         writer.WriteLine(line);
     }
}
```

3) Delete the log file and replace it with the temp file.

Or check out [this powershell answer](https://superuser.com/questions/117650/deleting-entire-lines-in-a-text-file-based-on-a-partial-string-match-with-window) for a one liner.

Answer (score 2):

If your file is small enough to fit into memory easily, I would tend to go for something like:

```
var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(log);
var filteredLines = allLines.Where(x => !x.Contains("PresenceManager"))
File.WriteAllLines(log, filteredLines)
```